# Connect a Biztalk send port to a ftps server

Tags: ftp, biztalk

I currently working on BizTalk and I got a problem when I try to configure a send port to a ftps server.

I send a request to an amazon server to get a file and I want to send this file on a ftp server.
I use an adapter nsoftware.ftp v3 for my sending port to the ftp server. But when I try it, I got this error message :

> This system contains a plaintext-only license, however the( Ftp:Adresse) send port is configured to run with security enabled. You must disable the security features for the send port to execute.

Do I need a certificate with a private key or just the configuration any is ok with the nsoftware adapter?

So actually I use a first flow to get a file on a amazon server and it works . After, I create a send port who must take this file and send him to an ftps server (it is the server of a client). So I use the property BTS.SPName to activate this send port at the file reception and I use a nsoftware.ftp adapter (free version) for the transport type. The client send to me the certificate of the server and I install it on the server.

Comment: please add detail what you have done

Comment: It looks like you need to buy a different license for the adapter to allow an encrypted connection. Or you need to disable encryption, if you do not need it and you want to stick with the license you have. It's actually not really clear, what do you ask for.

Comment: I add details and i will check if the license cover encrypted connection.

Comment: Have you tried using the included Adapters?  Both SFTP and FTPS are supported out of the box.

Comment: Yes, i tried it and i got an error message about the certificate hash i used ". Inner Exception details: "The specified client certificate hash is invalid. Provide a valid client certificate hash. ". ". That is  strange because i am sure to use the right hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martin is right. The error is due to licensing. The version of the license you have does not support SSL/TLS connections. Please [submit a support ticket](https://www.nsoftware.com/support/submit.aspx) and we can provide information on using the latest version of the adapters (V3 is also a few major versions old).

Comment: Thanks for you answer , we will see with our technical expert if we change our version or if we ask to the client to change his server( he create it just that).